# Why is Screen returning a lower resolution than my Windows 8 tablet is set to?

Tags: delphi, windows-8, tablet, dpi

I've got a Windows 8 tablet with a Full HD resolution of 1920x1080 pixel set.

But when I use Delphi's `Screen` object to get the `Screen.Width` and `Screen.Height` it will return a resolution of 1280x720 running on that Windows 8 tablet.

Where is the problem rooted? On the Windows (tablet) side or on the Delphi side? I use Delphi 7 up to XE2 with equal results. This seems to be rather a tablet problem than a general Windows 8 problem since I do not have such a behavior on my Windows 8.1 desktop machine.

---

*Conclusion*

*I just wanted to highlight the cause of my problem since it is kind of hidden in the comments.

By default Windows 8 on my tablet is using 150% DPI. 1080px are 150% of 720px. So 720px are usable by applications. Decreasing the DPI percentage to 100% results in the expected 1080px resolution.*

Comment: How sure are you that the machine has full HD?

Comment: Well thats what Windows says. And it "looks" like it too. What else can I do instead of setting resolution to 1920x1080 on the tablet?

Comment: Do Monitor.Width and Monitor.Height return the same values?

Comment: Yes, Monitor returns the same values.

Comment: Here's a little test... press the PrintScr key. That'll take a snapshot of the desktop.  Paste into Windows Paint, and then crop the image to eliminate white borders.  Is the resulting image 1920x1080 pixels or not?

Comment: I've made the screenshot and and saved it with Paint. Its dimension is 1920x1080. But opening the PNG on my desktop computer it looks like all the windows, menus etc. are double sized now.
So obviously my tablet is pretending to have a resolution of 1920x1080 but actually has not. Or it using 1280x720 internally (and which is effectively usable by apps) and scaling that up to 1920x1080 for the display.

Somehow both answers contain valid information so I'm not who to give credit.

Comment: @ErikVirtel, as I said, your device was designed to use 720p as a native resolution, such as are most tablets. The fact that you can force 1920x1080 just furthermore confirms what I said which is that `Full HD` means that the device can support HD resolutions **up to** 1080p.

Comment: @Erik Have you set custom DPI setting, or whatever it is called in Windows 8, to 100% before the screen shot test? I highly suspect 1920x1080 would be available as a resolution option if the display did not natively support it.

Comment: Thanks Sertac. This actually resolves my problem. As default the tablet is using 150% DPI. Decreasing it to 100% now results in the expected resolution. Unfortunately it is very inconvenient to work at 100% with the tablet.

Comment: @Erik - That probably means Torbin was right. You can probably make your application DPI aware to resolve. And, yes I agree, I know how it's like to work on a really high ppi screen with 100% DPI, really painful!

Comment: @ErikVirtel, which tablet are you using if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I've got an Acer Iconia W7 here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be DPI-related problem. Aero can handle high-DPI situations in two ways:

- Say to the application, that DPI is greater than standart 96, and let it scale itself
- Lie to the application, that DPI is usual 96, and scale it's window with some image-scalling algorithm (produces blur)

May be in the second situation Aero  is lying not only about DPI, but also about screen resolution.

---

If the second scenario is your case, then DO NOT turn off scaling. Just make your application DPI-aware:
http://www.rw-designer.com/DPI-aware - general info
http://www.micro-isv.asia/2010/09/high-dpi-support-in-windows-vista-and-7/ - delphi

Comment: A setting that Microsoft should never have made available in Windows.

Comment: I don't agree with you, Jerry. This setting is the only thing that let as hope to have retina-displays on desktops some time in future.

Answer (score 2):

Definition on Full HD is debatable.

Industry has adopted the term Full HD as the consumer-friendly marketing term to mean the device is a safe purchase because it can display at least one of the available HD resolutions.

Your device supports an aspect ratio of 16:9 which is the international standard for HD.

The two most publicly known `full HD` resolutions are :

- 1280 x 720 (720p)
- 1920 x 1080 (1080p)

The fact that your device says that it is `full HD` simply means that the display of the device at a minimum supports a resolution of 720p, up to 1080p.

Given that this is a tablet it should become apparent that it's native resolution is 720p HD.
The fact that you can force 1080p just means exactly that, a display marked as `Full HD` which is able to display 1080p. Does not mean 1080p is it's native resolution.

To answer your question, Delphi **neither** Windows is at fault.

Comment: I've never seen "full HD" to mean anything lower than 1080p. Here, f.i., [full HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Full_HD&redirect=no) redirects to 1080p.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Officially both 720p and 1080p are considered "full HD". Everyone thinks that `Full HD` is 1080p because that is how it's been marketed for a long time. In fact the only way to be sure that the device natively supports 1080p is if it states : `full HD 1080p`. Without that 1080p there is no guarantee and this is something that the industry exploits with great success.

Comment: I'd like to see your *official* reference.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, what is official to you? wiki? Even if you check 1080p wiki page it clearly states : `often marketed as Full HD`, 1080p that is. I regret saying officially because the phrase "Full HD" is not official and was made up by the marketing industry as I said in my answer. The definition on full HD is debatable. There are many great articles that touch this topic such as : [Full HD: Hip or Hype](http://www.digitaltrends.com/opinion/full-hd-hip-or-hype/).

Comment: 1) No, wiki is not official to me. I just noted my personal experience and gave an example. 2) "it clearly states often marketed as full HD",  yes that's what I'm saying. You won't find similar statement for 720p. 3) I disagree. Personally, I've never seen any debate/confusion on what "full HD" is. Maybe "HD ready", but not "full HD". But that's my opinion/experience, obviously yours is different. (PS: The article you linked seems to define full HD as 1080p. Do I read it wrong?)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I understand what you mean, in my country, full HD is also often advertised as 1080p, but the point that I was trying to make is that companies are not duty bound to respect the association of `full HD = 1080p` because they made it up and there is no international law defining full HD as 1080p. Personally I have seen devices advertising full HD but fail to actually deliver. In fact one might argue that any device with a display that markets as full HD but doesn't have the screen to accommodate the resolution is actually false advertising. Doesn't apply to projectors ofc.